# How to get commit and tree using Revparse with nodegit?

Tags: nodegit

I'm trying to use nodegit to get the tree of a commit based on a reference or oid using Revparse, I thought the following code would work, however I'm getting getTree undefined errors:

```
return git.Repository.open(path_to_repo)
    .then((repo) => git.Revparse.single(repo, "other"))
    .then((commit) => commit.getTree());
```

How do I cast the object returned by Revparse to a commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `RevParse.single` returns an [Object](http://www.nodegit.org/api/object/) which really is just a low level libgit2 object. That will have to have its [type](http://www.nodegit.org/api/object/#type) checked to make sure it's an `Object.TYPE.COMMIT`. If it is then you can grab the [OID](http://www.nodegit.org/api/object/#id) and use that to get the actual [Commit](http://www.nodegit.org/api/commit/).

Since NodeGit is really just bindings to libgit2 there's isn't (currently) any way to really cast an object from 1 thing to another. You have to do the lookups yourself.

Now if you're just trying to get the commit that a given reference points to you could modify your code to this:

```
return git.Repository.open(path_to_repo)
    .then((repo) => repo.getReferenceCommit("other"))
    .then((commit) => commit.getTree());
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved this by: `return git.Revparse.single(repo, rev).then((object) => git.Commit.lookup(repo, object.id())).then((commit) => return commit.getTree());`